# How to select an input inside a form, which ID contains dots

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following form:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input id="my.input.blabla"></input>
</form>
```

How would I select the input if it contains the dots?

Something like

```
document.getElementById("myForm").getElementById("my.input.blabla");
```

doesn't work.

Comment: `.` no matter `document.getElementById("my.input.blabla")` even works

Answer (score 4):

All you need is a single call to `getElementById()`:

```
var inp = document.getElementById("my.input.blabla");
```

The values of "id" attributes must be unique, so there's no point in scoping the lookup to a particular part of the page.

Comment: I am actually working with JSF + Richfaces and have a couple of forms in a View. Every form has an input type called javax.faces.ViewState and I would like to retrieve it from one of them. This is why I want to get the form first.

Comment: @dukable, check my answer, it might help you in the scenario you described

Comment: @dukable it doesn't matter whether the input is in a form or not. If it has an "id" value, then the "id" must be unique, JSF or no JSF.  If your page ends up with the same "id" on multiple elements, then it is broken.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is that getElementById() is a document's function and not a DOM element's function.

The dots makes no different.

the id attribute should (in valid HTML document) be unique and there is no reason to specified the parent element (the form in your example).
You can use:

```
document.getElementById("my.input.blabla");
```

If your HTML document contains more than one element with the same id and you can't change it (not you document, creating a browser extension etc.) you can try to use one of the following functions which does exist in a DOM element:

```
some_dom_element.getElementsByClassName 

some_dom_element.getElementsByTagName
```

You can try something like this:

```
// Get the form
var my_form = document.getElementById('myForm');

//Get all input elements in the form
var inputs = my_form.getElementsByTagName('input'); 

for (var i = 0; i< inputs.length ; i++ )
{
    var tmp_input =  inputs[i];

    // Get the element's id and check if it's the one you need
    if (typeof tmp_input.getAttribute !== "undefined")
    {
        var input_id = tmp_input.getAttribute ('id');

            //if(input_id === "the id you are looking for")
            if(input_id === "my.input.blabla")
            {
                /// Found the input element, use it here 
                break;
            }
    }   
}
```